# Obtain subsets of data frame with special conditions and store in separate dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
time  count   class   flag
  t1   876      10     1
  t2   900      10     1
  t3   910      10     1
  t4   934      10     1
  t5   871      10     1
  t6   880      14     2
  t7   800      14     2
  t8   812      14     2
  t9   877      14     2
  t10  865      14     2
```

I want to create a set of data frames that look like this:

```
DF1
  time   count  class
  t3   910      10     
  t4   934      10     
  t5   871      10     

DF2
 time   count  class
  t2   900      10     
  t3   910      10     
  t4   934      10      

DF3
 time   count  class
  t1   876      10     
  t2   900      10     
  t3   910      10    

DF4
 time   count  class
  t8   812      14     
  t9   877      14     
  t10  865      14
```

and so on. The number of rows in each data frame can be changed so probably a function that takes in the original data frame and a number and gives me a set of data frames each with rows=number. The grouping is done based on flags. and I need to start creating from the bottom. so for each flag, as shown here, the data frame starts to be made from bottom.

Comment: why is it divided into 4 when there are only 2 flags?

Comment: I have only shown 4 here but there will be more. I have just shown 4 here. @enke

Comment: It is not quite cleat what your goal is... so you have multiple flags in one big dataframe ? and in every group of flags you want to split to smaller pieces by a number? Should that number be the length of the new dataframe or is it the start index ? .....or is it completely different :P

Comment: @Rabinzel The number should be the length of the new data frame and it should start from the last index within that flag. I hope that is clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use `windowed` function from [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to create a list of the rolling window, for example:

```py
> list(more_itertools.windowed(range(5), n=3))

[(0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)]
```

Apply this function to pandas group:

```py
import more_itertools


dfs = (df.groupby('flag')
         .apply(lambda group: list(map(lambda ids: group.iloc[list(reversed(ids))],
                                       more_itertools.windowed(reversed(range(len(group))), n=3))))
         .tolist())
```

Then use the `flatten` function from `more_itertools` to flatten the list of list

```py
dfs = list(more_itertools.flatten(dfs))
```

```
[  time  count  class  flag
2   t3    910     10     1
3   t4    934     10     1
4   t5    871     10     1,   time  count  class  flag
1   t2    900     10     1
2   t3    910     10     1
3   t4    934     10     1,   time  count  class  flag
0   t1    876     10     1
1   t2    900     10     1
2   t3    910     10     1,   time  count  class  flag
7   t8    812     14     2
8   t9    877     14     2
9  t10    865     14     2,   time  count  class  flag
6   t7    800     14     2
7   t8    812     14     2
8   t9    877     14     2,   time  count  class  flag
5   t6    880     14     2
6   t7    800     14     2
7   t8    812     14     2]
```